# html css resize image from tileset

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I'm pulling an image from a tile set at the size of 50px x 50px. I want to be able to make this image depending on what size I want it. Is there a way to pull out this image and resize it without having to deal with background-size? Perhaps pull this image into a div and resize the div?

```
img.tileone
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:
url(images/summertile.png) -1px -1px;
}
```

Say for example I'm pulling out a tile 50 x 50 but I want to resize it 75 x 75.

Comment: what about changing the whole picture's size and the size of the div and then making the overflow hidden?

Comment: you have a background image and you wan't to give it a size. But you don't want to set the background image size???

Comment: When I change the size of the image it pulls out more from the tileset. The image I'm pulling out is 50 x 50, and if I change it to 75 x 75 it pulls out half of the next image.

Comment: I thought the background-size only changed the size of the tileset. If I do that how can I get the image pixel perfect out?

For example, if the div is 100px, and the image needs to be 33.3%, how can I make sure I'm pulling out the correct image from the tileset?

I thought there would be a way to pull out the image at 50 x 50, then treat it as a single image to change its size.

Comment: When you say tileset - i think you mean **sprite** :)

Comment: @Danield yes I do! I'm only just starting on this project so I'm getting used to new terms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `css sprites` you must give them fixed width and height.

This means that there is no way to get them to resize dynamically.

If however you know a fixed set of new dimensions you might need for your div -

**You could :**

1) Add new variations of the image within the sprite or

2) Use scale to take care of this. Something like this:

```
.tileone {
   background-image: url(images/summertile.png) -1px -1px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
   transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
 }
```

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten so far! It's unfortunate I can't change the size pixel specific, but I can change my other code to make this work. Thank you!

My code is

`img.tileone {`
`width: 50px;`
`height: 50px;`
`background: url(images/summertile.png) -1px -1px;`
`-webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);`
`transform: scale(1.5,1.5);`
}

Comment: Forgive the format of that, I can't seem to figure this site out.